# How to Error Check in VBScript For Loop

Tags: excel, vbscript

How do I stay in the "For Loop" if I have an Error.  I want to fill in the Excel sheet cell with "Unknown" if an Error occurs.

```
Function AddCommonDetail(ByVal ColCount)
  for i = 1 to ColCount 
    WorkSheet.Cells(row, i).Value  = DataSet(i).value
  Next
```

End Function

Comment: I don't know where your DataSet(i) comes from but before relying on exception handling, make sure there are no way to check for valid data. Does your Dataset has a IsNull or IsEmpty property? If it has, use it, your code will be cleaner.

Comment: DataSet comes from a Stored Procedure.  There are roughly 600 records.  The writing to the spreadsheet fails on the 11th record on a Date field.   This is a DB2 database and the 11th record does return a valid date as does all the other records, but for some reason attempting to write out this date to the spread sheet creates an error and the *.wsf file bombs out.  The Stored Procedure does the Error checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Function AddCommonDetail(ByVal ColCount)
  ' This tells it to just continue to the next statement if there's an error
  On Error Resume Next

  for i = 1 to ColCount 
    WorkSheet.Cells(row, i).Value = DataSet(i).value
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      Err.Clear
      WorkSheet.Cells(row, i).Value = "Unknown"
    End If
  Next
```

Comment: Had to put On Error Resume Next inside the function for it to work.  THANKS.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the code in my answer.  Don't forget to mark it as the answer if it worked for ya!

Comment: @Buddy you need to put either `OERN` or `Err.Clear` inside the loop, otherwise all the next items after the first error occurrance return `Unknown`.